# Negating Java 8 reference to Predicate method

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, predicate

In Java 8, it is possible to refer to unary methods which return a `boolean`/`Boolean` (e.g. [`Collection.contains(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)) using [method reference syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), returning an equivalent `Predicate` object for the referent method:

```
final Set<Integer> acceptedValues = new HashSet<>();
final Predicate<Integer> isValueAccepted = acceptedValues::contains;
```

Moreover, the negation of this object can be retrieved by using [`Predicate.negate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#negate--):

```
final Predicate<Integer> isValueNotAccepted = isValueAccepted.negate();
```

However, **is there no shorthand for directly negating a method reference itself?** — for example, the following expressions are not compilable:

- `final Predicate<Integer> isValueNotAccepted = acceptedValues::contains::negate;`
- `final Predicate<Integer> isValueNotAccepted = acceptedValues::contains.negate();`
- `final Predicate<Integer> isValueNotAccepted = !acceptedValues::contains;`

---